# HTML table cell issue

Tags: html

I am brand new to front end HTML and trying to construct a table identical to the below example whereby I have cell numbering identical to this.[image: the objective]

My code as it stands when rendered looks like this. [image]

I am struggling to figure out how I achieve the cell numbering. I have done a few things but it looks out of sorts.  Is this done via colspan.

```
<table border="1">
          <tr>
            <td>Bruce Springsteen Born To Run</td>
            <td><img src="images/borntorun.jpg" alt="bruce springsteen"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Thunder Road</td>
            <td>4.47</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>10th Avenue Freeze Out</td>
            <td>3.10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Night</td>
            <td>3.00</td>
          </tr>
            <td>Backstreets</td>
            <td>6.29</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Born To Run</td>
            <td>4.29</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>She's the one</td>
            <td>4.29</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Meeting Across The River</td>
            <td>3.15</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jungleland</td>
            <td>9.33</td>   
        </table>
```

Comment: The numbers would likely just be another column which your code appears to be missing

Comment: Go look up what rowspan/colspan do, and then use an extra cell for the numbers.

Comment: I think the keyword you are looking for is `colspan`. Use it in the first row for the first element and add an additional column for all other rows.

Comment: I suggest just add one more column to it

Comment: i have tried adding another TD, it skews to the other side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Bruce Springsteen Born To Run</td>
        <td><img src="images/borntorun.jpg" alt="bruce springsteen"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Thunder Road</td>
        <td>4.47</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>10th Avenue Freeze Out</td>
        <td>3.10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Night</td>
        <td>3.00</td>
      </tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Backstreets</td>
        <td>6.29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Born To Run</td>
        <td>4.29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>She's the one</td>
        <td>4.29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td> 
        <td>Meeting Across The River</td>
        <td>3.15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>Jungleland</td>
        <td>9.33</td>   
    </table>
```

You can use this and add 1 column to it and you can get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap and make it responsive as well, if you need more info [search here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp), example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">      
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
      Bruce Springsteen Born To Run
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:pink;">
      <img src="images/borntorun.jpg" alt="bruce springsteen">    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:yellow;">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5" style="background-color:pink;">
         Thunder Road  
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5" style="background-color:pink;">
      4.47    
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:yellow;">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5" style="background-color:pink;">
         10th Avenue Freeze Out
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5" style="background-color:pink;">
      3.10   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `colspan` to do it.

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Bruce Springsteen Born To Run</td>
    <td><img src="http://www.trait-tech.com/uploads/T-TOOL-9406__Acrylic-Mirror-Effect-3d-Wall-Decals-Flower-Shaped-Mirrors-Stickers-Pack-of-5-Set-for-Halloween-Chirstmas-Valentine-.jpg" alt="bruce springsteen"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Thunder Road</td>
    <td>4.47</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>10th Avenue Freeze Out</td>
    <td>3.10</td>
  </tr>
  <!--Other rows here-->
</table>
```